# Unusual cross-browser error with 'padding' at the bottom of the page

Tags: html, css

I searched on StackOverflow for this but nothing seemed to be exactly the same as this problem. On my website, there is some unexpected 'padding' at the bottom of the page. This padding varies depending on the browser you are using. It's hard to show a decent comparison but here's an image nonetheless:

[image: Browser comparison of footer]

Here's the code:

```css
body{
 background-color:blue;
}
#main::before{
 width:900px;
 height:113px;
 content: " ";
 position:absolute;
 top:-113px;
 left:0px;
 background-image: url('https://i.stack.imgur.com/7DE7i.png');
 background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
#main{
 position: absolute;
 top: 50%;
 left: 50%;
 width:900px;
 margin-top:100px;
 margin-bottom:150px;
 background-image: url('https://i.stack.imgur.com/zZCB2.png'); 
 background-repeat: repeat-y;
 height:80%;
 margin-right: -50%;
 text-align:center;
 transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
#main::after{
 width:900px;
 height:100px;
 content: " ";
 position:absolute;
 bottom:-100px;
 left:0px;
 background-image: url('https://i.stack.imgur.com/DVJAq.png');
 background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div id="main"></div>
</body>
```

I'm guessing it's to do with the margin/padding/positioning, but as you can tell, that's pretty much the entirety of the code. What is causing this, and how is it fixed? Or are there any alternative ways to format my images and get the same result without the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm pretty sure your culprit here is this style: `transform: translate(-50%, -50%);`

Change this style to this: `transform: translateX(-50%);` and then change your `top` definition to `top:113px;` to match your `::before` height.

```
#main{
    position: absolute;
    top: 113px; /*matching ::before height*/
    left: 50%;
    width:900px;
    margin-top:100px;
    /*margin-bottom:150px;*/
    background-image: url('http://www.thefunnyzone.co.uk/images/body.png');
    background-repeat: repeat-y;
    height:80%;
    margin-right: -50%;
    text-align:center;
    transform: translateX(-50%);
}
```

See this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/y559jfkh/2/).

In regards to the `translate` property - the original space occupied by the element will remain intact, as if the element hasn’t moved

Comment: May be worth adding the updated code here so that when that link stagnates, it will still be accessible to others!

Answer (score 0):

It looks to me like it's your margin properties in the `#main` css rule:

```
margin-top:100px;
margin-bottom:150px;
```

Remove these lines and your padding should be gone.

Example here:
https://jsfiddle.net/6y8eok9f/

Comment: Look at your fiddle in IE, it's still there